# How to track email open rate sent by codeigniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am working on a CodeIgniter project which involves sending bulk mail to a lot of email addresses. I want to track how many of them were actually delivered.? How can it be done..?

Help Appreciated.

Comment: I would look into using something like Mailchimp. Depending on how many email addresses you're sending to, you might be able to use their free account. I won't make any assumptions, but it sounds like this is spam-related...

Answer (score 1):

This is usually done in the following way:

```
<img src="http://mydomain.com/email_tracker.php?email=X&..." style="width: 1px; height: 1px; display: none;" />
```

And `email_tracker.php` you will have the code for tracking the emails

**Explanation**

You generate the image HTML when you send the email, and generally add a user id, email or similar information (uniquely identified).

When the users opens the email, the image is loaded, and a request is made to `email_tracker.php?...`, and this is how you can track the emails.

**Note**

This is not 100% accurate. If the user has images disabled, you will not be able to see if he opened the email or not.

**PS:**

This checks how many were opened. There is no real way of knowing which were delivered successfully. You will have to parse your logs in order to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tracking by the following way:

http://www.phpdevtips.com/2013/06/email-open-tracking-with-php-and-mysql/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=email-open-tracking-with-php-and-mysql

Answer (score 0):

In case you're sending plain-text emails where images cannot be added, you would create a unique link for each user. However, this will only work if they click the links.

I would combine both methods for the best result, even for HTML-based emails. Some users click the links, but do not load the images.

Answer (score 0):

there is a library call sendgrid it has a plugin with codeigniter with that you can check weather email deliver read and all

[please see here](http://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/codeigniter.html)